# Retrieve raw email headers with exchangelib

Tags: python, office365, exchange-server

I've been able to use exchangelib to log into my organization's Office 365 email and retrieve messages with Python. Now, given a message, I want to retrieve all its raw headers. `item.headers` provides only some headers; `To` and `From`, for example, are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20171010154257/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614(v=exchg.140).aspx) says you can use an extended property called `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS`, which has tag `0x7d` and type `String`. Here's a complete example that prints the raw headers of the first message in your inbox.

```
import exchangelib as E

user = 'wgates@microsoft.com'
password = 'hunter2'

class RawHeaders(E.ExtendedProperty):
    property_tag = 0x7d
    property_type = 'String'
E.items.Message.register('rawheaders', RawHeaders)
E.items.MeetingRequest.register('rawheaders', RawHeaders)

print("Logging in…")
account = E.Account(
    primary_smtp_address = user,
    autodiscover = True,
    credentials = E.Credentials(username = user, password = password),
    access_type = E.DELEGATE)

print(account.inbox.all()[0].rawheaders)
```

Comment: headers is a attribute of the class exchange.items.Message and shows all required details. Rest of the headers can be retrived via property_tag set as shown in above example. Information can be seen in link withing ExtendedProperty.py file